# how to test multi platform application in MyEclipse on the device?

Tags: android, ios, testing, myeclipse, multiplatform

I am using MyEclipse for multi platform development for Android and iOS, I'm using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap, I wonder if there is any way to test my project on my iOS Device.

The documentation only describes how to test the simulator and how to make the distribution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this documentation:

http://genuitec.com:8080/help/topic/com.genuitec.eclipse.mobile.doc/html/tutorials/build_app/index.html?cp=2_6_1_1

It seems to describe what you want to do. The same documentation is available in the product help.

Comment: A documentação não parece explicar como depurar no dispositivo, apenas para criar o aplicativo para distribuição na AppStore.
O que eu preciso para depurar o aplicativo

Comment: The mobile tools, currently in MyEclipse, are early release and will be enhanced as future releases come out. As yet, there is no debugging capability for mobile applications. I wouldn't expect MyEclipse to provide debugging facilities on the phone itself, though.